# No usb, no wired network after installing 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, usb, dell

I formatted and installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell E1505. Now Ubuntu starts faster. But Ubuntu doesn't recognice USB Drives, TouchPad, Ethernet or Wifi. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

might be good to post your hardware configuration so people would have idea how to solv you problem. Perhaps you can submit the result of "**lspci**"

Comment: *-network UNCLAIMED 
description: Network controller
product: BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n

vendor: Broadcom Corporation
  
physical id: 0

bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0

version: 01
   
width: 64 bits

clock: 33MHz

capabilities: bus_master cap_list
 
configuration: latency=0

resources: memory:efcfc000-efcfffff 
memory:e0000000-e00fffff

Comment: *-network UNCLAIMED

description: Ethernet controller

product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
  
vendor: Broadcom Corporation
 
physical id: 0
 
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
 
version: 02

width: 32 bits

clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master cap_list
 
configuration: latency=64

resources: memory:ef9fe000-ef9fffff

Comment: I failed to mention that the only way that I can even navigate using a usb mouse is not by booting normally from the hard drive, but by booting from a usb flash drive, and selecting install ubuntu on harddrive, then I cancel the installation and I am left with a mostly functional Ubuntu desktop.  If I boot normally from the hard drive, I have no usb, no touchpad...only keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue on my new build. Can you access the terminal from the Ubuntu desktop that way? I have been using the "Try Ubuntu" option because my network and mouse work, but there is no terminal. Running AsRock 75 Pro 3 w/ Intel I5 3.1 GHz quad and a Radeon HD 7870 GHz Edition.